# How virtualization works while allocating a virtual compute instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, virtualization, system-design

How Virtualization works when a compute instance is allocated by the primary computer.

Example:: How AWS or GCP allocates a computing instance from CPU lake or resource lake. What are the technologies these scenarios depends on, may be something like Docker or Kubernetes. How things work in behind.

Comment: It is a very broad research topic and the implementation could vary between the cloud providers. But this link can give you some basic idea: https://www.ukessays.com/essays/information-systems/virtual-machine-allocation.php.

Comment: Are you asking the relationship between an Amazon EC2 instance and an AWS IAM User, or are you referring to the allocation of physical hardware to an AWS customer?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I am asking about the hardware allocation to the customer like (CPU, Memory, Storage etc..)

Comment: @Shree That was a nice post, understood a lot of things. Btw thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i will talk about aws.

aws has the concept of vCPU.

- when we launch instanch we launch vCPU.
- Behind the scenes aws has cores which are nothing but CPU.
- MUtiple threads run on one cpu ( muti threading)
- Each thread given to you is represented as vCPU

for ex m5.2xlarge is launched, you get 4 cpu(behind the scene), 2 threads per cpu which means 2*4 = vCPu.

everywherein aws you will see metric as vCPU. [docs for reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-optimize-cpu.html)

Note:- **aws also gives you options to optimise these vCPu during launch of instance. you can reduce vCPU by either reducing no of cores ( to reduce license cost which cost on per core) or reducing no of threads per core ( to do high performing workloads)**

ALso you cant predict which core will be assigned for our vCPU it depends on demand and supply of instances, however they are ways to reserve instance through reserve instances or capacity reservation